# How to solve ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to unstack a MultiIndex Series so that I can plot the Series against one another.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dicts = {}

index = np.linspace(1, 50)
index[2] = 2.0
index2 = index.copy()
index2[3] = 3.0

for n in range(5):
    if n == 1:
        dicts['test' + str(n)] = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 20) ** (n / 5),
                                           index=index2)
    else:
        dicts['test' + str(n)] = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 20) ** (n / 5),
                                           index=index)

s = pd.concat(dicts, names=('test', 'displacement'))
s.unstack(level='test').plot()
```

The unstack() in the last line gets `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.  The other StackOverflow questions all seem to relate to pivot tables, but I'm not trying to aggregate data; simply plot it.

I would like to have 1 plot with 1 line for each test (level 0 of MultiIndex).  Each line would be the Series values versus the displacement (level 1 of MultiIndex).

My hack at the moment is:

```
for test_name, test in s.groupby(level='test'):
    test.index = test.index.droplevel()
    test.plot()

plt.show()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have duplicates in your `index`. Is there any reason for duplicating values in the index location?

Comment: Yes, it's raw data from many different tests and there will be lots of duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `append=True` in [`DF.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) so that it avoids the default writing entries all over again during `unstack` operation. It only adds the entries not present in the unstacked column before.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

df = pd.concat(dicts, names=('test', 'displacement')).reset_index()
labels = np.unique(df['test'].values).tolist()
df.set_index(['test', 'displacement'], append=True, inplace=True)
df.unstack(level='test').plot(figsize=(10,10), use_index=False,               
                              legend=False, title="Grouped Plot")
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=12, frameon=True, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image1]

---

Incase you want all the plots to start at the origin, you could use [`array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) to split the unstacked `dataframe` object into equal size based on the total length of the unique labels i.e 5 [*Test0* → *Test4*] as follows:

```
df = pd.concat(dicts, names=('test', 'displacement')).reset_index()
labels = np.unique(df['test'].values).tolist()
df.set_index(['test', 'displacement'], append=True, inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
for test_sample in range(len(labels)):
    np.array_split(df.unstack('test'), len(labels))[test_sample].plot(grid=True, 
                   use_index=False, ax=ax, legend=False, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=12, frameon=True, labels=labels)
plt.xlim(0,50)
plt.title("Grouped Plot")
plt.show()
```

[image: Image2]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need the data on the same axes so I can compare them.  The plot should look like my hack (in the question).  Is there a way to do that?            Ideally, the legend would read "Test0, Test1, ... TestN"

Comment: I love what you have done with the legend but the X axis gives 5 plots _next_ to each other, not superimposed.  Let me explain. In your example, you have appended X axes (one after another), not plotted on the same axis. If you run my question, with the hack plotting, you'll see what I'm trying to achieve.  Your example has the data on the same Y axis.  Surely, there must be a simple way to achieve the same on the X axis? Thanks for your help.